# Xpath expression to search nodes not relative to root node works for XML file but fails for XSD file

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd

This is my XML (wls.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

This the XSD (wls.xsd)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="note">
     <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

and this the java class i used to parse the above files using Xpath

```
public static void test1()
{
    String ipFile="w3s.xml";//wls.xsd

    Node fetchNode=null;

    FileInputStream fileip;
    try {
        fileip = new FileInputStream(new File(ipFile));

        DocumentBuilder builder =   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();      
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(fileip);

        System.out.println(xmlDocument.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        System.out.println(xmlDocument.getDocumentElement().getLocalName());
        evalXpath(xmlDocument,"//xs:element");//FAILS
        evalXpath(xmlDocument,"//element");//FAILS
        evalXpath(xmlDocument,"/schema/element");//WORKS
        evalXpath(xmlDocument,"/xs:schema/xs:element");//FAILS
        evalXpath(xmlDocument,"//heading");//FAILS



    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}


public static void evalXpath(Document xmlDocument,String expression)
{
    Node fetchNode=null;
    NodeList fetchNodeList=null;
    //String expression=null;
    try
    {
        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath(); 

        fetchNode = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println(fetchNode);

        fetchNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println(fetchNodeList.getLength());
    }
    catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}

}
```

The issue when I parse the XML file and run the expression of the type '\ElemName' it works fine and fetches the node. Not then I do the same for XSD file it returns NULL. 
For XSD I need to sue    '\RootNode\IntermediateNode....\ReqdNode'
I have tried this with name different XML and XSD, just attaching these short files for illustration purpose.

Issue2
Also there is one more issue:
say if I have an element 'xs:schema' and I need to get only the local name part (without namespace prefix) like 'schema', how can I do it? I have tried the getLocalName() but it doesn't work.

(I am using jdk6 if you need to know)

Please provide a resolution for atleast my first issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to get a XPath working on a XSD schema, make sure you declare the namespace from the XSD `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`.

If you don't want to use namespaces you can use XPath as follows:

```
//*[local-name()='element']
/*[local-name()='schema']/*[local-name()='element']
```

Comment: Hi @markdark, thanks for your reply.......the second point that you mentioned (local-name()) works fine :) ............ but I dint understand the schema thing. Because if you look at the schema I have posted in my main post (wls.xsd) it has this line '<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'... but it doesnt seem to work....please can you have a look at that also?

Comment: This comment is just to help others if they need to refer to an attribute of a element:                                //*[local-name()='element'][@id='1234'] ...ie no need to use local-name() for the attribute of an element.....Thanks for your solution Mark

Answer (score 0):

Nine years later :)

Could it be that you need to set `setNamespaceAware(true);`on the DocumentBuilderFactory instance?

I've read that the parser allowed an element to be named with o colon and not treat it as a namespace prefix in the early days, and default is false.

But if so, then I don't understand how "/schema/element" can work... :)